# Corda signs the built jar by default, but insists that i should add the signing credentials or set enable to false

Tags: corda

I have cloned the corda-training-template repo and had wanted to test signature constraints in Corda v4.x. Rather than getting a test key to sign the jar, I would go for the default corda dev key for convenience. However my understanding is that corda dev key is used as default if you don't put in any custom credentials, so that all jars are signed with it. However it keep printing out the error message during build as:

```
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':kotlin-source:jar'. > Exception while signing kotlin-source-0.1.jar, ensure the 'cordapp.signing.options' entry contains correct keyStore configuration, or disable signing by 'cordapp.signing.enabled false'. Run with --info or --debug option and search for 'ant:signjar' in log output.
```

The following is the original build.gradle for the kotlin-source with signing enable false removed:

```
repositories {
mavenLocal()
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed' }
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases' }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.publish-utils'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

cordapp {
targetPlatformVersion 4
minimumPlatformVersion 3
    contract {
        name "Corda Training Material"
        vendor "R3"
        licence "Contact R3 for Kotlin Source Contract License."
        versionId 1
    }
    workflow {
        name "Corda Training Material"
        vendor "R3"
        licence "Contact R3 for Kotlin Source Workflow License."
        versionId 1
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "../config/dev"
         }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "../config/test"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
     testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
     testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

     // Corda integration dependencies
     cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
     cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance-contracts:$corda_release_version"
     cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance-workflows:$corda_release_version"
     cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
     cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
     cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"
     cordaCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-webserver-impl:$corda_release_version"
     cordaRuntime "$corda_release_distribution:corda:$corda_release_version"
     cordaRuntime "$corda_release_distribution:corda-webserver:$corda_release_version"

     testCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-test-utils:$corda_release_version"
     testCompile "$corda_release_distribution:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"


      // GraphStream: For visualisation (required by TemplateClientRPC app)
      compile "org.graphstream:gs-core:1.3"
      compile("org.graphstream:gs-ui:1.3") {
      exclude group: "bouncycastle"
      }

      // CorDapp dependencies
      // Specify your cordapp's dependencies below, including dependent cordapps
      cordapp "$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance-contracts:$corda_release_version"
      cordapp "$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance-workflows:$corda_release_version"
      cordapp "$corda_release_distribution:corda-confidential-identities:$corda_release_version"
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
      kotlinOptions {
           languageVersion = "1.2"
           apiVersion = "1.2"
           jvmTarget = "1.8"
           javaParameters = true   // Useful for reflection.
      }
}

task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
      delete "./build/nodes"
      directory "./build/nodes"

      nodeDefaults {

            cordapp("$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance-contracts:$corda_release_version")
            cordapp("$corda_release_distribution:corda-finance-workflows:$corda_release_version")
            cordapp("$corda_release_distribution:corda-confidential-identities:$corda_release_version")
            rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "password", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
      }

      node {
           name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
           notary = [validating: false]
           p2pPort 10002
           rpcSettings {
                 useSsl false
                 standAloneBroker false
                 address "0.0.0.0:10003"
                 adminAddress "0.0.0.0:10103"
           }
      }
      node {
           name "O=ParticipantA,L=London,C=GB"
           p2pPort 10007
           webPort 10009
           rpcSettings {
                 useSsl false
                 standAloneBroker false
                 address "0.0.0.0:10008"
                 adminAddress "0.0.0.0:10108"
           }
     }
     node {
          name "O=ParticipantB,L=New York,C=US"
          p2pPort 10010
          webPort 10012
          rpcSettings {
                 useSsl false
                 standAloneBroker false
                 address "0.0.0.0:10011"
                 adminAddress "0.0.0.0:10111"
          }
     }
     node {
          name "O=ParticipantC,L=Paris,C=FR"
          p2pPort 10013
          webPort 10015
          rpcSettings {
                 useSsl false
                 standAloneBroker false
                 address "0.0.0.0:10014"
                 adminAddress "0.0.0.0:10114"
          }
     } 
 }

 idea {
      module {
          downloadJavadoc = true // defaults to false
          downloadSources = true
      }
 }
```

In response to the error message, i have added the following to the build.gradle under both cordapp (https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V4.0/cordapp-build-systems.html#signing-the-cordapp-jar) and deployNodes (https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V4.0/generating-a-node.html#signing-cordapp-jars) task in different permutations but the same error message asking for right keystore configuration keeps showing up:

```
 signing {
       enabled true
       options {
            keystore 
            alias
            storepass
            storetype
            keyalg
       }
 }
```

Without the mentioning about the credentials of the keystore or even specifying signing options, corda should build the jar with the default corda dev keys, but it isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

For a start the error message is misleading and doesn't say exactly what is happening within the java jarsigner tool (see ant signjar). Instead there is a likelihood that there is a problem with the jar such that jarsigner is unable to sign. SignJar.kt (Line 23 to 24) from the `corda core plugin` throws a generic error message when it encounters an error, so one would need to run the jar tasks with either --info or --debug mode, followed by scanning the messages for [ant:signjar].

In my encounter following running the jar signing task with --debug mode, showed an error message of the following:

```
 01:00:15.040 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:signjar] jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/LICENSE.txt
```

Likely the problem is while trying to fatjar (with other libs), the license files from other jars are causing a conflict. The resolution in my case is to exclude the license file from my build. Add the following to the build.gradle jar task.

```
 jar {
     duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
 }
```

After i have build the jar, I used the jarsigner tool (include in your JDK) to verify if the jar has been signed.

```
 jarsigner -verify <your jar.file name>
```

If its signed, it will output the following:

```
 jar verified.

 Warning:
 This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
 This jar contains entries whose signer certificate will expire within six months.

 This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2019-11-26) or after any future revocation date.

 Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.
```